# Problemas para desenvolver um jogo no estilo bricks breaking no tkinter (colisões com objetos)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, game

Estou alguns dias estudando e tentando fazer com que a bola ao bater nos retangulos de cima eles sumam e invertam o lado

```
 from tkinter import *
 from constantes import *
 import random 
 class Jogo():
     def __init__(self):

          #Criar tela principal

          self.root = Tk()
          self.root.geometry('%ix%i' %(LARGURA, ALTURA))
          self.root.title('Arcade')
          self.root.resizable(False,False)

          #Criar frame para conter o canvas

          self.frame = Frame(bg='blue')
          self.frame.pack()

          #Criar canvas

          self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg='blue', width=CANVAS_L, height=CANVAS_A, cursor='target')
          self.canvas.pack()

          #Criando objetos dentro do canvas

          #self.canvas.create_line(10,10,390,390,            fill='white')

          self.comecar = Button(self.root, text='INICIAR', command=self.comecar )
          self.comecar.pack()

          self.novoJogo()


     def novoJogo(self):
          #Criar objetos do jogo
          self.player = self.canvas.create_rectangle(195,360,280,375, fill='white')
               #Criar a bolinha
          raio = 29
          p = (100,200)
          self.ovo = self.canvas.create_oval(p[0],p[1],p[0]+raio,p[1]+raio, fill='grey',)
          #Velocidade da bola
          self.b_vx = 7
          self.b_vy = 7
          #Posição da bola
          self.b_x, self.b_y = p

          self.r = []
          for i in range(3):
               c = random.choice(['green', 'yellow','red'])
          #retangulos superiores horizontais
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6,10,80,30,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(82,10,160,30,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(162,10,240,30,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(242,10,320,30,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(322,10,398,30,fill=c)
          #retangulos superiores verticais 2ª FILEIRA
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6,32,80,52,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(82,32,160,52,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(162,32,240,52,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(242,32,320,52,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(322,32,398,52,fill=c)
          #3ª FILERIRA
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6,54,80,74,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(82,54,160,74,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(162,54,240,74,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(242,54,320,74,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(322,54,398,74,fill=c)
          #4ª FILEIRA
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6,76,80,96,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(82,76,160,96,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(162,76,240,96,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(242,76,320,96,fill=c)
          r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(322,76,398,96,fill=c)
          self.r.append(r)

          self.jogando = True

     def comecar(self):
          self.jogar()

     def jogar(self):
          if self.jogando:
               self.update()
               self.root.after(5, self.jogar)
          else:
               self.acabou(self.msg)

     def update(self):
          self.canvas.move(self.ovo, self.b_vx , self.b_vy)
          #atualizar o movimento da bola e sua posição
          self.b_x += self.b_vx
          self.b_y += self.b_vy
          #verificar se a bola esta batendo dos lados
          if self.b_x > CANVAS_L - 29 or self.b_x < 0:
               self.b_vx *= -1
          if self.b_y > CANVAS_A - 29 or self.b_y < 0:
               self.b_vy *= -1
          #verificar se existe colisões com os objetos
          self.verificar_colisao()

     def verificar_colisao(self):
               #Criar uma boulding box para capturar a posição da bola
          coord = self.canvas.bbox(self.ovo)
          colisoes = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*coord)
          print(*colisoes)
         # print(coord)
          #se o numero de colisões é diferente de 0
          if len(colisoes) != 1 :
          #verificar se o id do objeto colidido é diferente do id do objeto player
               if len(colisoes) != self.player:







if __name__ == '__main__':
     Jogo()
```

Comment: Todos os seus retângulos são `r`? Você não mantém uma referência para cada retângulo ou isso não é necessário?

Comment: Sinceramente estou meio perdido mas eles devem estar referenciados para que o programa reconheça eles

Answer (score 1):

Ok - eu ajustei  o seu código para passar a dificuldade que você encontrou - mas não me contive e escrevi um pouco mais de código até ele se tornar jogável.

A principal mudança feita, e que tem a ver com o ponto onde você colocou sua dúvida é - você não estava guardando cada retângulo criado do lado do Python - sim, o tkinter mantinha uma referência interna para cada retângulo e isso permitia que ele achasse as colisões e até permitiria que os retângulos onde houvesse colisão fossem apagados - mas sem uma referência do lado do Python, você não teria com contar quais retângulos foram destruídos, e contabilizar pontos, ou detectar o final da fase.

Dito isso: não faz sentido você escrever um programa para controlar um computador que faz ~10 bihões de operações por segundo, e ter que colocar as coordenadas dos seus retângulos manualmente, não é??

Então - baseado nas coordenadas que você estava desenhando, eu modifiquei o código para desenhar todos os retângulos em dois laços - o computador faz as contas -  gente só coloca os parâmetros como "largura do retângulo".

COm isso e um append para cada retângulo em "self.r", uma chamada a `self.canvas.delete` e `self.r.remove` dentro da verificação de colisões esta resolvido o ponto que você perguntou.

Alem disso, eu refatorei algumas coisas - em particular valores absolutos não devem ficar dentro do código - ainda mais quando você se deu ao trabalho de ter um módulo separado só com essas constantes. (que voce não colocou junto com o código - eu tive que desfazer a importação e achar valores razoáveis para as suas constantes). De qualquer forma, coloquei alguns outros valores como constantes a serem definidas antes do código.

E por fim, outra mudança mais perceptível é que adicionei código para receber os clicks do mouse e atualizar a posição do jogador - com isso, e mais a detecção de colisão com retângulos e o chão, deixando o jogo funcional.

```
from tkinter import *
import random 

LARGURA, ALTURA = 460, 410
CANVAS_L, CANVAS_A = 420, 380
PLAYER_L, PLAYER_A = 85, 15
RAIO = 29
PLAYER_VEL = 12

class Jogo():
    def __init__(self):

        #Criar tela principal

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('%ix%i' %(LARGURA, ALTURA))
        self.root.title('Arcade')
        self.root.resizable(False,False)

        #Criar frame para conter o canvas

        self.frame = Frame(bg='blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        #Criar canvas

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg='blue', width=CANVAS_L, height=CANVAS_A, cursor='target')
        self.canvas.pack()

        #Criando objetos dentro do canvas

        #self.canvas.create_line(10,10,390,390,           fill='white')

        self.comecar = Button(self.root, text='INICIAR', command=self.comecar )
        self.comecar.pack()

        self.novoJogo()


    def novoJogo(self):
        #Criar objetos do jogo
        self.v_basica = 7
        self.p_x = 195
        self.p_y = 360
        self.p_alvo_x = self.p_x
        p_x2 = self.p_x + PLAYER_L
        p_y2 = self.p_y + PLAYER_A
        self.player = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.p_x, self.p_y, p_x2, p_y2, fill='white')
        #Criar a bolinha
        p = (100,200)
        self.ovo = self.canvas.create_oval(p[0],p[1],p[0]+RAIO,p[1]+RAIO, fill='grey',)
        #Velocidade da bola
        self.b_vx = self.v_basica
        self.b_vy = self.v_basica
        self.v_player_x = PLAYER_VEL
        #Posição da bola
        self.b_x, self.b_y = p

        self.r = []
        offset_x, offset_y = 4, 8
        rect_height = 20
        rect_width = 80
        rect_spacing = 2
        for line in range(4):
            for column in range(5):
               c = random.choice(['green', 'yellow','red'])
               x1 = offset_x + (rect_width + rect_spacing) * column 
               x2 = x1 + rect_width
               y1 = offset_y + (rect_height + rect_spacing) * line
               y2 = y1 + rect_height
               r = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,fill=c)

               self.r.append(r)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.mover_player)
        self.jogando = True

    def comecar(self):
        self.jogar()

    def jogar(self):
        if self.jogando:
             self.update()
             self.root.after(30, self.jogar)
        else:
             self.acabou(self.msg)

    def mover_player(self, evento):
        self.p_alvo_x = max(0, evento.x - PLAYER_L // 2)
        print(self.p_alvo_x)

    def update(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ovo, self.b_vx , self.b_vy)
        if self.p_x != self.p_alvo_x:
            sinal = -1 if self.p_x > self.p_alvo_x else 1
            mudanca_player = sinal * self.v_player_x
            if self.p_x + PLAYER_L + mudanca_player < CANVAS_L or self.p_x + mudanca_player > 0:
                self.p_x += mudanca_player
                sinal2 = -1 if self.p_x > self.p_alvo_x else 1
                if sinal != sinal2:
                    self.p_alvo_x = self.p_x
                self.canvas.move(self.player, mudanca_player, 0)

        #atualizar o movimento da bola e sua posição
        self.b_x += self.b_vx
        self.b_y += self.b_vy
        #verificar se a bola esta batendo dos lados
        if self.b_x > CANVAS_L - RAIO or self.b_x < 0:
             self.b_vx *= -1
        if self.b_y < 0:
             self.b_vy *= -1
        if self.b_y > CANVAS_A - RAIO:
            self.msg = "Bolinha atingiu o chão"
            self.jogando = False
        #verificar se existe colisões com os objetos
        self.verificar_colisao()
        if not self.r:
            self.msg = "Fase concluida"
            self.jogando = False

    def verificar_colisao(self):
        #Criar uma boulding box para capturar a posição da bola
        coord = self.canvas.bbox(self.ovo)
        colisoes = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*coord)
        print(*colisoes)
        # print(coord)
        #se o numero de colisões é diferente de 0
        if len(colisoes) != 1 :
        #verificar se o id do objeto colidido é diferente do id do objeto player
             self.b_vy *= -1
             for item in colisoes:
                if item not in self.r:  # colisão com a propria bola ou com o player
                    continue
                self.canvas.delete(item)
                self.r.remove(item)

    def acabou(self, msg):
        print("Fim de jogo")
        print(msg)
        input()
        quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Jogo()
    mainloop()
```

Não modifiquei seus comentários - e mantive a mecânica de atualização da bolinha para os player - Se você for continuar o jogo a partir daí, precisa agora modificar a função "acabou" para exibir avisos com tkinter, e não com "print" e "input", e ajustar novoJogo até que funcione quando for chamada uma segunda vez.

Um sistema de pontos também seria legal! :-)